# Marlin Z-probe Failure!

Tags: bed-leveling, z-probe, homing

I'm using Marlin. Recently my Z-probing randomly doesn't work. Sometimes during Z-Homing **it goes up** instead of going down to sense the Bed! In  Bed Leveling it goes higher and higher every time. It got frustrating so I ignored Bed-leveling.

Sometimes I get a fine Z-homing but it always **starts printing in the air!!!** I have no Idea why it happens. All home and axis offsets and setting are fine. I had no problem last time I used my printer.
Why my printer starts printing **5 mm** in the air?

Comment: Out of the blue? Or, did you change something recently?

Comment: My MKS Gen_L V1 and tmc2100 drivers on X,Y axis fried for unknown reason! I replaced them with the same board and LV8729 drivers. then I changed the settings for the new drivers.

Comment: I had problems with z-probing before that! I guess this maybe related to what happened to my board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I'm using an aluminum structure for my gantry. My Chinese power supply was in contact with this structure. There was a current leak from my power supply that was messing with the Z-probe signal.
I detached the power supply, everything's gotten back to normal, except it had my board and TMC2100 drivers fried a week ago.